# Convert Azure Storage account (classic) to ARM Blob Storage

Tags: powershell, azure

I have some Azure Classic Storage accounts that are used only to store Blobs -- no Files, no Tables, and no Queues. [From what I've read](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/storage-create-storage-account), it will be far more efficient and cost-effective for me to ensure that when I convert these to ARM, their "Account kind" is set to "Blob storage" and not "General purpose".

I recently converted a Classic Storage account successfully using [this guide from Microsoft](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/virtual-machines-windows-ps-migration-classic-resource-manager), but when I check its properties, its "Kind" is "Storage", which I take to mean "General Purpose". I also created a Storage account from scratch and specified its "Account kind" to be "Blob storage", and when I check that one's properties, "Kind" is "BlobStorage" (the goal).

I didn't see a way to specify what I want the resulting "Kind" to be when I performed that conversion in PowerShell, so I'm not certain that what I'm asking is even possible. **Is there a way I can ensure that when I convert my Classic Storage account to the ARM architecture through PowerShell, it will be Blob Storage instead of General Purpose Storage?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there a way I can ensure that when I convert my Classic Storage
>   account to the ARM architecture through PowerShell, it will be Blob
>   Storage instead of General Purpose Storage?

As of today, it is not possible to convert a `General Purpose` Storage account to a `Blob` Storage account. You would need to copy the contents from one account to another yourself.

Things you can do today with a storage account:

- For a storage account you can change the redundancy level between `LRS`, `GRS` and `RAGRS`. You can't change the redundancy level if the Storage account's redundancy type is `ZRS` or `Premium LRS`.
- You can change the access tier between `Hot` and `Cold`.

Comment: I do see that there is no way to convert an ARM General Purpose to an ARM Blob Storage. However, I have a Classic Storage right now, before the distinction between General Purpose and Blob Storage existed. Are Classic Storage accounts considered to be General Purpose, thereby making General Purpose the only option when a conversion from Classic to ARM is performed?